# Can't generate Chosen select using Rails helpers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, select, jquery-chosen

I have styled beatiful select, but I need to connect it to database, so I have simple html code:

```
<select class="chzn-select" tabindex="1" style="width:300px;" data-placeholder="Choose a Category">
            <option value=""></option> 
            <option value="Fashion">Fashion</option> 
            <option value="Coupon">Coupon</option> 
            <option value="Sport">Sport</option> 
    </select>
```

and code using rails form helpers:

```
  <%= f.select :category, options_for_select(%w[Fashion Health Travel Food Coupons]), :class => "chzn-select"%>
```

**EDIT: Add html code generated by rails :**

```
     <select id="website_category" name="website[category]"><option value="Fashion">Fashion</option>
  <option value="Health">Health</option>
  <option value="Travel">Travel</option>
  <option value="Food">Food</option>
   <option value="Coupons">Coupons</option></select>
```

It shows me blank page, however code is generating due to I see it in my Google console.

I should set all other attributes or what is porblem ?

Comment: Im not sure what your asking here...Is the select tag not visible

Comment: Edited title. My select tag, that I generating by Rails Helper is not visible, but chose select, that I created using simple html is visible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was needed to call it correctly from js file:

```
         $("#website_category").chosen();
```

Answer (score 0):

What does you generated code look like? Can you post that?

If you're not generating any options, maybe try:

```
<%= f.select :category, options_for_select(["Fashion", "Health", "Travel", "Food", "Coupons"]), :class => "chzn-select"%>
```